# Openstreet with leaflet not appearing on some desktop and all mobile browser

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mobile

I have set up osm on ubuntu below is how my codes are. The issue the map appears perfectly on desktop browser but it doesnt appear on mobile phone browser. What could be issue? Is there any tweak needed for some those desktop or laptop and all mobile support?

```
                               <div id="map" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:230px;right: 0; bottom: 0;width:calc(100%-230px);height:65%;">

                         </div> 
                         <div id="dataTable" style="overflow: auto;position:absolute;left:230px;right: 0; bottom: 0;width:calc(100%-230px);height:35%;background:#eeeeee;">
                    <div class="x_panel">
                          <div class="x_title">
                            <h2>Vehicle List </h2>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                              <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                  <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li><a class="close-link" onclick='closeDataTable()'><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="x_content" id="tableContent">

                            <table id="dashboardGrid" class="table " >
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                      <th>Group</th>
                                      <th>Sub Group</th>
                                      <th>Stat.</th>
                                      <th>Veh. #</th>
                                      <th>View</th>

                                      </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody >


                                  </tbody>
                                </table>


                          </div>
                       </div>
                         </div>

                       </div>
```

Below is how is my init function for map to appear in the div.

```
function init() {
             var map = L.map('map');

             //add a tile layer to add to our map, in this case it's the 'standard' OpenStreetMap.org tile server
             L.tileLayer('http://*.*.*.*/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                maxZoom: 18
             }).addTo(map);

             map.attributionControl.setPrefix(''); // Don't show the 'Powered by Leaflet' text. Attribution overload

             var london = new L.LatLng(-1.935114,30.082111); // geographical point (longitude and latitude)
             map.setView(london, 13);
             var redMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
                    icon: 'fa-motorcycle',
                    markerColor: 'orange-dark',
                    shape: 'circle',
                    prefix: 'fa'
                   });
                   var myPopup = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'infoWindow');
           myPopup.innerHTML = "<div id='info'><p id='title'>title</p><p>address</p></div>";
                   L.marker([-1.935114,30.082111], {icon: redMarker,}).addTo(map).bindPopup(myPopup);
                   //L.marker([-1.935114,30.082111], {icon: redMarker,}).addTo(map).bindPopup('<strong>Science Hall</strong><br>Where the GISC was born.');




                }
```

I have even tried a very basic example.

```
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://*.*.*.*/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                maxZoom: 18
             }).addTo(mymap);

    L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();

    L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a circle.");



</script>
```

Comment: I have some basic demos I've been making for a school project, they may help. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/

Comment: @BillChappell  I have added below is my basic example even that is not working but both the circle and pop-up is appearing.

Comment: Your OSM tile layer URL is not valid.   http://*.*.*.*

Comment: @BillChappell no its valid is a local ip to my local server. The reason cause it works on my desktop perfectly.

Comment: If you are using a local IP to hit your server, can the mobile also hit the same IP? Are you running your page from localhost or from the same server your tiles are at?

Comment: No I have one as the webserver(Centos) and one is the map server(Ubuntu). The local ip is behind a firewall and have no access directly from the outside world. Only access is via the webserver. What is haunting me it works from my desktop. But all other places is does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64448/discussion-between-bill-chappell-and-user8012596).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, it's your code. I hit OSM a little different then you but..

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>

<script>

 var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    var osm=new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{ 
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'});
    osm.addTo(mymap);

  //  L.tileLayer('http://*.*.*.*/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  //              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  //              maxZoom: 18
 //            }).addTo(mymap);

    L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();

    L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a circle.");


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got time out with your codes.

Comment: I presume that `http://*.*.*.*` is handled automagically by leaflet; is that so?  And what does Leaflet replace it with? (should I RTFM or should this be its own question?)

Comment: @Alex I just hide my local ip thats all it works via my desktop actually.

Comment: That's probably your issue then.  If you're hosting your page off an [RFC1918 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (e.g. 192.168.x.x) then you won't be able to access it over the cell network.  Try turning WiFi on on your mobile.

Comment: @Alex yes I have turned my wifi but on my desktop even when I am out from the vpn it works.

Comment: @Alex just to add the webserver is on a public ip so I am access via the public ip not the local ip

Comment: VPNs can be [tricky beasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling).

Comment: @AlexHajnal what is your suggestion then to access the map server via the webserver?

Comment: Just a request: In future please post the _exact_ code that you're having problems with.  If you redact something then say that did so.

Comment: @AlexHajnal this the exact codes which I am running and having issues.

Comment: That's probably better asked on [Networking.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) or somesuch.

Comment: You're using `*.*.*.*` as a valid IP address? (!)

Comment: @Alex ok that portion is my mistake and sorry for that is a local ip

Comment: Probably well outside the scope of GIS.SE but in a nutshell what you need to do is set up a static inbound NAT rule on your external router to point to your dev map server then adjust your code to use the public IP and port instead of the private IP and port.  Do the same for any other services on private addresses that your code is accessing.

Comment: @AlexHajnal so no choice I got to put it on a public ip is it?

Comment: Either that or get access over WiFi working on your mobile devices.  This really looks like a networking issue.  It sounds like you're in a corporate environment.  I'd talk to your IT department about this.

Comment: @AlexHajnal yes I notice ip I put a public ip for ex. http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png the page seems to be working. So meaning the map server need to be on a public ip

Comment: That is correct.  (Or, to be more specific, it must be _reachable_, not necessarily public)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong but I've got a hunch that `width:calc(100%-230px)` may be evaluating to `0`.  Have you tried using  a divide-and-conquer approach?  i.e. iteratively remove half of the non-essential code until the problem disappears.  That should at least help isolate the problematic code.

Comment: yes the 230px is indeed my right hand side panel where I show some relevant data. Which half should I remove I am not quite sure on this ?

Comment: I have tried a very basic example is the same issue though. I have updated my question with my basic example too.

Comment: I would try removing the `width:…` clause entirely.  The idea is to get the code to work, not to get it to work and look absolutely perfect.  If that bit of code is indeed causing problems then you can try achieving the same effect using a different approach.  If removing it doesn't fix things then you'll know that the problem (probably) lies elsewhere.

Comment: I have updated with my very basic example too. Its the same the code is very basic. When I tried to run the basic example the circle and pop-up appear but the page does not get loaded is like keep loading how to check the error on mobile phone?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because in production my server had https certificate and in development doesn't. What happens is in my mobile app it did not appear the message that it was an unsecure connection. When I copied a link of one tile image from geoserver WMS and paste to the mobile browser the message of unsecure connection appeared. After I selected that I approve to go to the unsecure connection, in that tile image, and later entered in the web app it started to appear all tile images from GeoServer.