# How can I fix mobile view on Joomla 3?

Tags: openstreetmap, mobile, joomla

I read the discussion ([Openstreet with leaflet not appearing on some desktop and all mobile browser](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253349/openstreet-with-leaflet-not-appearing-on-some-desktop-and-all-mobile-browser/353908#353908)) but I don't know where to find this code and fix it on Joomla 3. I used a plugin (Fields - GMapFP OpenStreet Map) that works fine on desktop browsers but doesn't show nothing on mobile (android/chrome). [image: desktop view] [image: mobile view] Link: [my website](https://www.musemolise.it/cosa-facciamo/turismo-in-molise)

Comment: Where is the map on your website? I don't see it and my Italian isn't the best, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi! The map is here: [link] (https://www.musemolise.it/cosa-facciamo/turismo-in-molise)